# What is the best approach or sustainable for hosting multiple php versions' projects in a server?

Tags: php, production

I have a new CentOS server, plan to use it for all the php projects, currently i have many php 5.6+ projects & one php 7 project at two different servers. We knew we will upgrade the php version or even mysql version in future, so what is the trend or approaches for hosting different versions of php projects?

Did some researches about Docker & Rancher or install multiple PHP versions in one server and controlled by ngnix. But still not sure which one is the best approach, first option seems need to understand well about dockers or kubernetes, the learning curve will be higher.

Currently Cloud environment is not in my consideration. All these projects are system tool and applications (intranet, CRM), not eCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP via FPM (FastCGI Process Manager), which is available for all recent PHP versions including the older releases like PHP 5.6. This is true at least for Ubuntu when using [Ondrej's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php). I guess there should be a way to achieve parallel PHP installations in CentOS as well.

With FPM you could use Nginx as well as Apache as your webserver. I would recommend Nginx, but it's up to you. There are plenty of tutorials for both of them.

Then, you would configure each *virtual host* according to your needs to use PHP 5.6 or 7.x respectively. With FPM pools each *virtual host* can be configured independently, even dedicated php.ini files are no problem.

Have a look at [this blog post](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/), which is quite to the point from my personal view.